# vertical text spacing without extra space above and below paragraphs

Tags: css

As I want some pixelperfect aligning of my texts i am looking for a way to determing the space between the ascenders and the previous element and the spacing between the baseline and the next element.

This example shows perfectly how I would like the spacing between the paragraphs and other elements by matching the font points to the line height pixels.

```
p {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 25pt;
    line-height: 25px;
    margin: 20px 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3v9ms/

It has perfect spacing between the divs and the paragraphs and also has perfect spacing between the 2 paragraphs. However the spacing between the lines of a paragraph is now 0. I want it to be 25px.

But when i increase line-height this also creates more room at the top and bottom of the paragraph that causes the spacing from ascenders/baseline to previous/next element to get out of order.

```
p {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 25pt;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin: 20px 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gC3Mx/

How can one set a spacing between lines of a paragraph without adding spacing to its top or bottom?

I have tried negative margins on the paragraphs but it makes it nasty as it would produce barely readable CSS and weird effects when you change the order of elements (for example when i use negative top and bottom margins on paragraphs, this messes up when i do 2 paragraphs after eachother but works great when i have another element in between.

Comment: You can see the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409905/how-to-prevent-line-height-from-adding-a-margin-in-the-top

Comment: You must change your markup to get what you want... :\

Comment: But how would i change markup without making it a complete mess and with elements affecting eachother in unpredictable ways. what would be a best practice to rewrite this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is a bad practice but you may get desired result by using 
`p:first-line`

check this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gC3Mx/1/

Comment: unfortunately this does not work in FF. also it does not fix the bottom.